# "@Bean methods are valid only when declared within a @Configuration annotated class" error

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I am trying to make a Hello World app using Spring MVC and JavaConfigs instead of XML files. I read that you can declare a bean using @Bean if the class is annotated with @Configuration. I have a class annotated with @Configuration and a method inside annotated with @Bean.

I'm getting an error message within IntelliJ 12 (red underline error):

> @Bean methods are valid only when declared within a @Configuration
>   annotated class

And the following error message on Tomcat 7.0.37 startup:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [S:\dropbox\Shared Folders\Majerus Eric (BBY)\SpringMVCBarebones\target\SpringMVCBarebones\WEB-INF\classes\com\springapp\mvc\WebAppConfig.class]; nested exception is java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire org.springframework.config.java.annotation.Bean.autowire()
```

**WebAppConfig**

```
package com.springapp.mvc;

import org.springframework.config.java.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.springapp.mvc")
@Configuration
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

**WebAppInitializer**

```
package com.springapp.mvc;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;


import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        // Create the 'root' Spring application context.
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context.
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(WebAppConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

As an example, I used this tutorial: [Migrate Spring MVC servlet.xml to Java Config](http://www.luckyryan.com/2013/02/07/migrate-spring-mvc-servlet-xml-to-java-config/) and also Spring documentation on WebAppInitializer.

My git repo is hosted on Bitbucket [here](https://bitbucket.org/ackmanx/spring-mvc-javaconfig-barebones/src).

Comment: The posted code works fine here, using 3.2.6.RELEASE. What version of spring are you using? Are you using @Bean anywhere else in your code?

Comment: @SheenaArtrip I am using 3.2.6.RELEASE too. That is the only @Bean. My other class is `public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer`, which I configured using [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html). If I try to startup tomcat, I get `SEVERE: Context initialization failed
... Failed to read candidate component class: file [ ... \com\springapp\mvc\WebAppConfig.class];`

Comment: That works fine too. Post your WebApplicationInitializer too. What container are you running in? What do your removed imports look like?

Comment: @SheenaArtrip I updated my post to answer your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at your pom, you have spring-javaconfig added. spring-javaconfig has been merged into spring 3.X so you should not need it. Remove it and it should run fine.

Comment: Removed that extra dependency, deleted the old import in WebAppConfig for @Bean and it worked! Thanks